# Android ArrayAdapter and ListAdapter conflict

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to perform a search in a listview. Listview gets all info from db and displays them. The problem is that ArrayAdapter of search has a conflict with ListAdapter of listview. Because search doesn't work if it's performed before ListAdapter then if I place it below ListAdapter search works but on the other page arne't displayed other informations.

```
 private void updateList() {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        Set<String> unionSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : mPlatesList) {
            for(String key : hashMap.keySet())
                if(key.equals(TAG_TARGA))
                    unionSet.add(hashMap.get(key));
        }

        String[] table = unionSet.toArray(new String[unionSet.size()]);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.plates_search, R.id.plates_search, table);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                Lista.this.myAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPlatesList,
                R.layout.plates, new String[] { TAG_TARGA, TAG_NGJYRA, TAG_MARKA, TAG_SIGURACION, TAG_GJOBA, TAG_PRONAR, TAG_SGS },
                new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.ngjyra, R.id.marka, R.id.siguracion, R.id.gjoba, R.id.pronar, R.id.sgs});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                String targa = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                String ngjyra = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ngjyra)).getText().toString();
                String marka = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.marka)).getText().toString();
                String siguracion = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.siguracion)).getText().toString();
                String gjoba = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.gjoba)).getText().toString();
                String sgs = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sgs)).getText().toString();
                String pronar = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pronar)).getText().toString();
                String username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Username");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Lista.this,Info.class);
                intent.putExtra("Targa",targa);
                intent.putExtra("Ngjyra",ngjyra);
                intent.putExtra("Marka",marka);
                intent.putExtra("Gjoba",gjoba);
                intent.putExtra("Siguracion",siguracion);
                intent.putExtra("Sgs",sgs);
                intent.putExtra("Pronar",pronar);
                intent.putExtra("Username",username);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that `R.id.title, R.id.ngjyra, R.id.marka, R.id.siguracion, R.id.gjoba, R.id.pronar, R.id.sgs`  that are displayed on the other page are empty if search is above ListAdapter otherwise info on the other page are displayed but search doesn't works. What to do?

Comment: so u mean u cannot retirve data from one page to other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer here for CustomSearch Feature, u need to write CustomAdapter for that -->[ReferThis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911915/autocompletetextview-doesnt-show-dropdown-when-i-press-space-after-typing-a-com)

```
    public void search() {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        Set<String> unionSet = new HashSet<String>();
        List<Map<String, String>> mPlateClone = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(
                mPlatesList);
        for (Map<String, String> hashMap : mPlateClone) {
            for (String key : hashMap.keySet())
                if (key.equals(TAG_TARGA))
                    unionSet.add(hashMap.get(key)); 
        }

        String[] table = unionSet.toArray(new String[unionSet.size()]);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        // myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.plates,
        // R.id.title,
        // table);
        // lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // // ((SimpleAdapter)
                // //
                // adapter).getFilter().filter(inputSearch.getText().toString().trim());
                ((SimpleAdapter) Lista.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(
                        inputSearch.getText().toString().trim());

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `OnItemClickListener` you should not read from the list but from your data source. You got `position` passed for that reason, so you should be able to retrieve right, corresponding data from `table`

Comment: But from the table I get only "Targa" not "Ngjyra", "Marka" etc... I need those others in order to display on the other page

Comment: Then you may rethink if you are using proper Adapter. Apparently `StringAdapter` is too limited. Use `ArrayAdapter` for example and have your data in datasource complete

Comment: I am using ArryaAdapter what do you mean?