# AutoCompleteTextView not showing all relevant suggestions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am making an Deck Building app using an AutoCompleteTextView and everything appeared to be fine until one of my users reported it was not working correctly.

The view should auto-complete based on a list of card names provided, but doesn't seem to show all of the relevant options.

For example the following names are in the view

> "Flooding at Sweet Apple Acres" "Save Sweet Apple Acres" "Sweet Apple
>   Acres" "Sweet and Kind"

Typing "Sweet" into the view will show all of these values, but typing "Sweet " (with a trailing space) or "Sweet A" will only return the results "Sweet Apple Acres" and "Sweet And Kind" even though all of the other options are valid.

If there is a space in the text field it seems to ignore any auto-complete options that don't start with the given text. Is there any way to change this? I'm using the basic AutoCompleteTextView using default settings.

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoText = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_name);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, CardDatabase.CARD_NAMES);
        autoText.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Custom adapter for this

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {


private Context context;


private List<String> originalData;
private List<String> filteredData;

private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public CustomAdapter(List<String> itemList, Context ctx) {

    originalData = new ArrayList<String>();
    filteredData = new ArrayList<String>();

    filteredData = itemList;
    originalData = itemList;

    context = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null);
    }

    final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.textView);

    text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        Filter.FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            filterableString = list.get(i);

            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I found another solution and haven't tested this one, but it looks very similar to the one I found.

Comment: convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.textView); ??? Where did you find this testView ??

Comment: @ManojBehera which layout you are using?

Answer (score -1):

Immediately after posting I had a revelation and reworded my question to google and came across this
[AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show dropdown when I press space after typing a complete word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911915/autocompletetextview-doesnt-show-dropdown-when-i-press-space-after-typing-a-com)

which linked to this
https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/95d127a0fdd1c7c2520650081fadedb4d54ffe32/src/com/luksprog/dp/adapter/FilterWithSpaceAdapter.java

and solved my issue.